Обособление вводного сочетания «должно быть»
Какой вариант пунктуационного оформления вы выберете? Поменяется ли значение от того или иного варианта?
Эти два человека, должно быть, фрилансеры, усердно работающие за компьютером.
Эти два человека, должно быть фрилансеры, усердно работающие за компьютером.

Я бы выбрал такой вариант: Эти два человека — должно быть, фрилансеры, усердно работающие за компьютером.

Слава, да, я тоже не против вашего варианта.

Мой однозначный вариант:
Эти два человека, / должно быть, / фрилАнсеры, // усердно работающие за компьЮтером.
Предложение по смыслу и интонации делится на две полноценные фонетические фразы. Вводное слово выделено небольшими произносительными паузами.
О грамматике предложения
Вводное слово должно быть входит в основное предложение (без оборота) и стоит между подлежащим и сказуемым.
Сравнить (без вводного слова): Эти два человека – фрилансеры. Или: Эти два человека – фрилансеры, усердно работающие за компьютером.
Вводное слово* является "разделителем" между подлежащим и сказуемым (вместо паузы, обозначаемой тире)
Розенталь, пункт 1 (примечание)
Обычно тире не ставится: 4) если между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит вводное слово, иногда — наречие, союз, частица: Дубава, кажется, друг Корчагина (Н. О); Риск, как известно, дело благородное; Необдуманный поступок вообще шаг опасный; Сергеев теперь известный художник; Пихта тоже дерево смолистое; Март только начало весны.

Интересно, то есть вы считает, что "должно быть" относится к концовке, а не к началу?

К первой, конечно же.   Оно входит в основное предложение (без оборота) и стоит между подлежащим и сказуемым.  Сравнить (без вводного слова): Эти два человека –  фрилансеры. Или: Эти два человека – фрилансеры, усердно работающие за компьютером.   Разделителем  между подлежащим и сказуемым является вводное слово (вместо паузы, обозначаемой тире)

Просто выделение жирным, я думал, это вы так хотите показать, что "дб" связано с тезисом в конце.

А корректно ли вообще относительно придаточное разбивать вводным словом? Вот в чем вопрос. К чему относится вводное? К подлежащему или сказуемому?

Я предлагаю такой вариант. Эти два человека, усердно работающие за компьютером, должно быть фрилансеры.

У меня другая грамматика. И смысл другой. Я вижу двух человек и предполагаю, кто они.  Эти два человека, / должно быть, / фрилАнсеры, которые целый день усердно работают за компьЮтером.  А какой еще тут смысл, я не могу понять. //Вы перестраиваете предложение, но грамматика неясная, как и пунктуация.  А если неясная, то стиль нехорош.  Надо идти от смысла ситуации: кто, кому и что говорит.  У вас это непонятно. //  И произношение ваших вариантов для меня тоже загадка. Всё  должно быть гармонично, в том числе графика текста.  А когда одно другому противоречит, это не есть хорошо.

Откуда вообще эти примеры, есть ли контекст? Как можно что-то обсуждать, если мы не понимаем, что это.

Я просто про оформление, вот это понятнее: Эти два человека, / должно быть, / фрилАнсеры, которые целый день усердно работают за компьЮтером, - чем выделенное жирным шрифтом.

Грамматика понятнее, чем в случае причастного оборота.  // У Сержа: Эти два человека, усердно работающие за компьютером, должно быть фрилансеры Здесь другой смысл, как бы диалог: Я  вижу двух людей, усердно работающих за компьютером.. Наверное,  они фрилансеры.  – С чего  ты это взял?

Смысл предложения: два человека, которые работают усердно, — фрилансеры. У нас с вами один и тот же смысл. Поэтому вводное слово я предполагаю поставить в конец.

С вводным словом в середине предложения смысл может не совсем ясен. Будто бы усердно работают фрилансеры. Между тем я вижу здесь приложение.

Шарон, следует ли разрывать причастный оборот?

Серж: "Между тем я вижу здесь приложение".
Без вводного сочетания ("фрилансеры" использовано как приложение):
Эти два человека, фрилансеры, усердно работающие за компьютером.
Здесь вообще нет сказуемого.
Можно написать так:
Это два человека, должно быть фрилансеры, усердно работающие за компьютером.
Или так:
Эти два человека, должно быть фрилансеры, усердно работают за компьютером.

Рима, я знаю, что приложение. Я спрашивал о другом. Насколько корректно было использовано вводное слово в середине.

Второй ответ по комментариям

Менять структуру предложения не получится – смысл будет разный. (1) Эти люди – фрилансеры, которые усердно работают. (2) Эти люди, которые усердно работают, – фрилансеры.

Но вы-то знаете смысл, и тогда ваши варианты такие:


Эти люди, усердно работающие, – фрилансеры, должно быть.
Или: Эти усердно работающие люди – фрилансеры, должно быть.
У фразы должна быть красивая графика, минимум знаков.

Сказуемое обсуждается? Сказуемое здесь одно – фрилансеры, других кандидатов нет. И тогда приложения быть не может.


Вы невнимательно читаете чужие ответы и комментарии, Sharon. Я отвечала на предложение Сержа в комментарии и процитировала его слова в своем ответе. (См.: С вводным словом в середине предложения смысл может не совсем ясен. Будто бы усердно работают фрилансеры. Между тем я вижу здесь приложение.) "Фрилансеры" могут быть приложением, но тогда само предложение Сержа нужно менять. Что я и обозначила. То есть обсуждалось не сказуемое, а приложение.
